# Phonegap build android doesn't do anything

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I created a phonegap app but when I run `phonegap build android` it seems everything works fine.

```
phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android' ...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android --no-telemetry'
```

But when I check the platforms/android/build folder to install the apk, there is a weird folder called `android-profile` and thats all. Theres no outputs/apk folders. All the other commands work fine like phonegap platform add, phonegap serve, phonegap platform rm.

I can run `phonegap build android` in any folder and I will get the same output. It doen't even check if the folder is a phonegap base app.

- phonegap v. 8.0.0
- npm v. 3.10.10
- node v. 6.11.3

Thank you!

Comment: Until you fix your local environment, you could try the online service (https://build.phonegap.com/)

Comment: have you tried using cordova instead of phonegap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that somehow I didn't have cordova installed O_O

After the installation and `coedova build android` it shows me the correct path of the apk

```
platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug
```

It probably changed because of the new phonegap version. Im glad I finally fix it. Thank you!